# SOAP Fault Error : internal Error

Tags: soap

```
SOAP Fault returned from TKS. 
SOAP Response:<NS1:Fault xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</NS1:Fault>
```

TKS is our program that is designed to receive financial information from other program so called eTKS and TKS and eTKS had been developed by two different companies.

While we are testing our programs, above soap-error notification occurred however, the problem is member of programmer of TKS and eTKS cannot specify on in which part the problem is occuring exactly.

We, the TKS part, are assuming the the pre-defined format has been violated from the eTKS sides, since TKS doesn't receive any file but just resulting above error  code.

However, eTKS, claims that there's no possibility of the format being modified since they allowed only one format being allowed before the out-send from eTKS.

They are arguing that above "Internal Error" denotes the problem resides in TKS.

Have anyone can advise how to resolve this problem concisely via specifying the problem?

Comment: It is a really generic error. No error in your server logs ? Also, there is a tool SoapUI that can act as a server or client for webservice. You can use this to find what eTKS send you and also generate a valid use case for your TKS